# Changing primary color in Shopware 5.4.6

Tags: shopware

I installed Shopware 5.4.6.

During the installation i set

```
**primary color** to #003e7f
```

now i wil change it but found no way.

could i do it using the backand UI?

i not found the colors by using menus in backand UI.
but i found `#003e7f`
inside of `/web/cache/1534073711_1c2b232742eb2c753938318d5facf73c.css`

```
.btn:hover { ... color: #003e7f;  ... }
```

And i did a fulltext search over the mysql database without result.

How could change this color correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change almost all colours directly in the theme settings in the backend. Please go to configration > theme manager > select your theme > configure theme. The backend will show you various configurations.

The setting you are looking for might be @brand-primary in the color configuration-tab.

[image]

Comment: i noticed that in bare theme is only "Icons & Logos" Tab. "Configuration" and "color configuration" is not there. is your screenshot from the bare theme?

Comment: The bare theme is completely without any styles and javascript. So there won't be any colour definition for the bare theme, as there are not styles in it. Only the responsive theme provides styles and javascript, the Bare theme is only plain html-content.

Please have a look at the documentation: https://developers.shopware.com/designers-guide/getting-started/#bare-and-responsive